# UML sequence diagram for a periodic operation

Tags: uml, scheduling, sequence-diagram

I have a scheduled operation in my spring boot application using spring boot [scheduler](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/).
this operation executes every period of time(30 minutes) and adds data in the database if conditions are met.
I was wondering how to model this operation in a UML sequence diagram.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I typically handle things like this with a simple note

[image]

It makes the point and doesn't require any fancy symbols.

See also [how to show event in a sequence diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228095/how-to-show-event-in-a-sequence-diagram)

Comment: thank you so much. this was really helpfull

Comment: @KamesGuen no problem. Also, consider if you need to be more formal with the time. "On the hour and half hour" says the same thing but also says when it will happen.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most appropriate way is to use a `loop` fragment:

[image]